# adding foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql

Can't find any question that really helps me so heres another.

I'm trying to set a foreign key constraint on a table (dempartment) and link it to the primary key on table (employee) the column is called (dno) on employee and called (dnumber) on department. Both fields are the same type, but I keep getting

```
mysql> alter table department
    -> add foreign key (dnumber)
    -> references employee (dno);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'dba110.#sql-938_3' (errno: 150)
```

any suggestions?

UPDATE:
So I'm trying to see if my dno and dnumber columns are signed or unsigned.

```
mysql> show create table employee;
+----------+-------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
| Table    | Create Table


+----------+-------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
| employee | CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `Fname` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Minit` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lname` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SSN` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `Bdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(27) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sex` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Salary` float NOT NULL,
  `Superssn` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dno` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------+-------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table department;
+------------+-----------------------------------------
-------------------------------------+
| Table      | Create Table
                                     |
+------------+-----------------------------------------
-------------------------------------+
| department | CREATE TABLE `department` (
  `dnumber` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `dname` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mgrssn` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+------------+-----------------------------------------
-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Have you created your department table before employee table? :-)

Comment: Based on your update of the question it is obvious why you get the error. Your table design is correct just need to swap the execution order of creating the two tables with foreign key reference in the employee table. Or do the alter employee, not department. Coz one department can have many employees.

Comment: any chance you can give me the code for that. Because I think I have tried both ways. One way gives me the error 1072 and the other way that your talking about gives me:
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'dba110.#sql-938_3' (errno: 150)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, one of the fields is UNSIGNED and the other is SIGNED.

You can check your columns by  [SHOW CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html).

More info is here: [MySQL Error Number 1005 Can’t create table ‘.\mydb#sql-328_45.frm’ (errno: 150)](http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/)

Comment: ok but how do I go about checking to see if they are signed or unsigned?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the correct table structure should be,

Employee having foreign key deptID.

E.g.

```
alter table employee add foreign key (dnumber) references department (dno);
```

If you have the ability to change the design, I suggest you keep dept a parent, and pull its id into employee for referential integrity. :-)

**Editing as per OP's comments**

PS: on mobile so the code snippet will not have code tags. And wish I could give you a sample in SQLFIDDLE.

Steps:

```
create table department
(dno int not null primary key, 
 dname varchar(15), 
 mgrno int UNSIGNED null)

Insert into department    
(dno, dname, mgrno)    
Values    
(),
(),
()
;

Create table employee
(eid int not null primary key, 
 ename varchar(25), 
 mid int not null, 
did int not null,
foreign key (did) references 
 department (dno))

Insert into employee
(eid, ename, mid, did)
Values
(),
(),
(),
(),
()
;
```

Please try above structure. So your primary keys are set, foreign keys are set. I only add most primary fields for both tables. You can add your other columns.

Comment: In my professor's instructions he talks about keeping referential integrity. But I tried your way and got the error:
ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'dnumber' doesn't exist in table

Comment: Your design is a little complicated as it has both circular dependcy and recursive associations. These type of relationships make your table schema elegant yet require you to manage it with fully scrutinity/proper order of alter/drop executions. I do not mean to make it confusing. But if you really intend to go about your design, you better read up on the topics please :) I could update my post with a simpler design or explaining the same above.